# sycn a vertical recyclerview with and horizontal recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am creating a food menu layout, the menu has categories with items.
at the top is a list of category names like drinks, sushi, etc, which is a recyclerview that scrolls horizontally, at the bottom are the category items for example under drinks there is cocacola Fanta, etc which is a recyclerview that scrolls vertically. I am trying to synch the two recyclerviews together with a behavior in which when you scroll the vertical, it scrolls the horizontal and vice versa.

I created this class to implement this feature.

```
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearSmoothScroller
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class TwoRecyclerViews(
    private val recyclerViewHorizontal: RecyclerView,
    private val recyclerViewVertical: RecyclerView,
    private var indices: List<Int>,
    private var isSmoothScroll: Boolean = false,
) {

private var attached = false

private var horizontalRecyclerState = RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
private var verticalRecyclerState = RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE


private val smoothScrollerVertical: RecyclerView.SmoothScroller =
    object : LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerViewVertical.context) {
        override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int {
            return SNAP_TO_START
        }
    }


fun attach() {
    recyclerViewHorizontal.adapter
        ?: throw RuntimeException("Cannot attach with no Adapter provided to RecyclerView")

    recyclerViewVertical.adapter
        ?: throw RuntimeException("Cannot attach with no Adapter provided to RecyclerView")

    updateFirstPosition()
    notifyIndicesChanged()
    attached = true
}

private fun detach() {
    recyclerViewVertical.clearOnScrollListeners()
    recyclerViewHorizontal.clearOnScrollListeners()
}

fun reAttach() {
    detach()
    attach()
}

private fun updateFirstPosition() {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        val view = recyclerViewHorizontal.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(0)?.itemView
        val textView = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.horizontalCategoryName)
        val imageView = view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.categorySelectionIndicator)
        imageView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        textView?.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
        textView?.setTextColor(recyclerViewVertical.context.getColor(R.color.primary_1))
    }, 100)
}

fun isAttached() = attached

private fun notifyIndicesChanged() {
    recyclerViewHorizontal.addOnScrollListener(onHorizontalScrollListener)
    recyclerViewVertical.addOnScrollListener(onVerticalScrollListener)
}

private val onHorizontalScrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        horizontalRecyclerState = newState
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        val linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager =
            recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?
                ?: throw RuntimeException("No LinearLayoutManager attached to the RecyclerView.")

        var itemPosition =
            linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

        if (itemPosition == -1) {
            itemPosition =
                linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        }

        if (horizontalRecyclerState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING ||
            horizontalRecyclerState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
        ) {
            for (position in indices.indices) {
                val view = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(indices[position])?.itemView
                val textView = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.horizontalCategoryName)
                val imageView = view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.categorySelectionIndicator)
                if (itemPosition == indices[position]) {
                    if (isSmoothScroll) {
                        smoothScrollerVertical.targetPosition = indices[position]
                        recyclerViewVertical.layoutManager?.startSmoothScroll(smoothScrollerVertical)
                    } else {
                        (recyclerViewVertical.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)?.scrollToPositionWithOffset(
                            indices[position], 16.dpToPx()
                        )
                    }
                    imageView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textView?.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
                    textView?.setTextColor(recyclerView.context.getColor(R.color.primary_1))
                } else {
                    imageView?.visibility = View.GONE
                    textView?.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL)
                    textView?.setTextColor(recyclerView.context.getColor(R.color.secondary_5))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private val onVerticalScrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        verticalRecyclerState = newState
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        val linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager =
            recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?
                ?: throw RuntimeException("No LinearLayoutManager attached to the RecyclerView.")

        var itemPosition =
            linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

        if (itemPosition == -1) {
            itemPosition =
                linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        }

        if (verticalRecyclerState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING ||
            verticalRecyclerState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
        ) {
            for (position in indices.indices) {
                val view = recyclerViewHorizontal.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(indices[position])?.itemView
                val textView = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.horizontalCategoryName)
                val imageView = view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.categorySelectionIndicator)
                if (itemPosition == indices[position]) {
                    (recyclerViewHorizontal.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)?.scrollToPositionWithOffset(
                        indices[position], 16.dpToPx()
                    )
                    imageView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textView?.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
                    textView?.setTextColor(recyclerViewVertical.context.getColor(R.color.primary_1))
                } else {
                    imageView?.visibility = View.GONE
                    textView?.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL)
                    textView?.setTextColor(recyclerViewVertical.context.getColor(R.color.secondary_5))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

the class works fine for the vertical scroll, but there is an instability with the horizontal scroll. if you also have a better solution than the class i created kindly share.

Comment: You'd probably be better off requiring a tap of the first recycler to select an item and then display that in the other cycler.  You'll have a lot fewer corner cases that way.

Comment: @GabeSechan the horizontal recycler has a behaviour similar to a tablayout of which when the screen loads the first item must be selected. thats why i have the function updateFirstPosition()

Comment: That's fine for the default selection.  What I'm saying is that trying to do it on scroll, rather than on selection, is going to cause you a LOT of pain, time, and bugs.  Do it on a selection tap and it becomes trivial-  just change the data in the second adapter in the onClickListener.  Which is actually exactly how tabs work-  you tap on a tab and it loads its data.  Doing it on scroll just opens up a ton of corner cases and makes it very hard to test.

Comment: @GabeSechan i have implemented it this way using a tablayout and recyclerview and it worked very well but the selecting on scroll didnt. thats why i decided to use two recyclerviews. left to i would use the tablayout and recyclerview but the client and po really want this feature. and i already warned them it may end up bugging the app.

Comment: Which RV list does the `indices` refer to?

Comment: @Zain both RV use the same indices cause it is just one list.

Comment: You Can't achieve this by two RecyclerView, Instead of Two RecyclerView you can use ViewPager as Horizontal RecyclerView. And on ViewPager you can easily get the category, And Based on that categories you can show the sub-categories on vertical RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve your UI/UX requirement is to use [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) with a vertical recycler view.

Both list items in the recycler view and tabs in the tab layout can be set up as a dynamic number of items/tabs

When you scroll up and down and reach the respective category, update the tab layout using the following code. You can identify each category from the

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs); // Once for the Activity of Fragment
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(someIndex); // Some index should be obtain from the dataset 
tab.select();
```

In the same way, when clicking on a tab or scrolling the tab layout, Update the RecyclerVew accordingly./

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(itemCount)
```

Hope this will help, Cheers!!